# Laravel WhereIn method in Eloquent not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I want to use the WhereIn method in Eloquent but it now works like the below function.

```
<?php 
  $product = DB::table('product')
                   ->join('supplier','supp_code','=','prod_supplier_code')
                   ->select('product.*','supplier.supp_margin')
                   ->where('prod_seo_title','=',$id)
                   ->first();

  $decArr = explode(',',$product->prod_decoration_type);

        for($i=0; $i<count($decArr); $i++)
        {
            if($i==0)
            $inString = "'".$decArr[$i]."','";
            elseif ($i<(count($decArr))-1)
            $inString .= $decArr[$i]."','";
            else
            $inString .= $decArr[$i]."'";
        }

        $proDeco = DB::table('decoration')->whereIn('deco_print_type', [$inString])->get();
?>
```

But In the query, it's displaying like this.

```
select * from `decoration` where `deco_print_type` in ('\'100109C9\',\'100110B9\',\'100144C9\',\'100186C9\'');
```

I can't understand why these slashes are coming. Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `whereIn()` method will accept an array of all the items. In your example you are passing an array with one element with all the values already concatenated. Based on your example you only need to pass `$decArr`

```
DB::table('decoration')->whereIn('deco_print_type', $decArr)->get();
```